# Get a value from mysql inside a while loop and use it from within the while loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some distinct numbers from a table i call `incoming_sms` and i want to insert a random value from another table `jobs_content` while at the same time using the numbers i have selected from `incoming_sms`.

This is my code

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT distinct(dest_msisdn)  FROM incoming_sms  where text_message like '%Acc%' AND in_date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY ) AND dest_msisdn in (SELECT msisdn FROM 20214_R4K)");


while($row = $result->fetch_array())
  {
  $distinct_number = $row['dest_msisdn'];

  /**
  select description into from jobs_content where category = 'Accounting' order by rand() limit 1;
  */

  $mysqli->query("insert into test_subject(the_number,the_description) values($distinct_number,rand())");

  }

$result->close()

?>
```

How can i use a real random value that i choose from table `jobs_content` in this line

`$mysqli->query("insert into test_subject(the_number,the_description) values($distinct_number,rand())");`

instead of using mysql's `rand()`?.

Comment: question not clear. explain please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving the variable i want to fetch the value from outside the while loop.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT distinct(dest_msisdn)  FROM incoming_sms  where text_message like '%Acc%' AND in_date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY ) AND dest_msisdn in (SELECT msisdn FROM 20214_R4K)");

$name = $mysqli->query("select description from jobs_content where category = 'Accounting' order by rand() limit 1")->fetch_object()->description;  

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
  {
  $name = $mysqli->query("select description from jobs_content where category = 'Accounting' order by rand() limit 1")->fetch_object()->description;

  $distinct_number = $row['dest_msisdn'];

  /**
  select description into from jobs_content where category = 'Accounting' order by rand() limit 1;
  */

  $mysqli->query("insert into test_subject(the_number,the_description) values($distinct_number,'$name')");

  }

$result->close()

?>
```